# Asset Pipeline in development

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

What are the steps I need to take in order to **use .js and .css** files through the asset pipline while in the *development* environment?

I put images, js and css in the appropriate app/assets folders and I put `*= require_tree .` in application.css and `//= require_tree .` in application.js but the page still doesn't look like it did with regular html referencing.

Do I need to precompile with `config.assets.precompile += %w( parallax.js )`? If so, where?

Also, do I need to run `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: No, you do not need to precompile assets for development environment. Your app should pick your assets from asset pipleline directly without compressing. In case, if you are deploying on heroku then you do not even need to precompile assets for production environment as well. As heroku will do that for you.

Comment: Try to hunt why your assets are not picked up instead of pre compiling them for development. That's all i can suggest.